# Use of unset and count with arrays

Tags: php, arrays, count, unset

I have a array that contains other arrays with each user's details in. For example:

```
$_SESSION["ActQueue"] = [["J.Paul", "John", "Paul", "0000-00-00 00:00:00"],["J.Bloggs", "Joe", "Bloggs", "0000-00-00 00:00:00"]]
```

I have written a bit of code that is mean to turn the "account rank" of the first user in the array to "Cadet" in the database. The code then removes the user from the array and then should either echo data = 1 or the next user in the list depending if they exist. I have done this with the following bit of code, however I have found that when unset deletes the first item it the keys don't shift down 1, so 0 will simply not exist and 1 will still be "J.Bloggs". As a result when the next user is echoed no values are sent. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
session_start();

require "classes.php";
$TF = new TF_Core ();

$ActQueueAccept = "UPDATE users 
    SET rank = 'Cadet' 
    WHERE username = ?";

if ($statement = TF_Core::$MySQLi->DB->prepare($ActQueueAccept)) {
    $statement->bind_param('s',$_SESSION["ActQueue"][0][0]);
    $statement->execute();
}

unset($_SESSION["ActQueue"][0]);

if(count($_SESSION["ActQueue"] != 0)){
    echo json_encode(['Username'=>$_SESSION["ActQueue"][0][0], 'Surname'=>$_SESSION["ActQueue"][0][1],'Forename'=>$_SESSION["ActQueue"][0][2],'Joined'=>$_SESSION["ActQueue"][0][3]]);
}
else{
    $data =  1;
    echo $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: in json_encode the indexes are 0 only $_SESSION["ActQueue"][0][0] this should be $_SESSION["ActQueue"][1][0] same for all

Comment: check the code only:- https://eval.in/686735  .And let us know what happen

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. If you are saying that I should echo $_SESSION["ActQueue"][1][0], then it won't work as the first item containing data must be 0. Otherwise the more times I loop through this the more times the first user gets shifted back, so I would end up doing $_SESSION["ActQueue"][45][0]. It would work in theory, but it seems far too much effort to track how many times something was deleted from the array.

Comment: @Anant, what does that do exactly. It seems you are completing the process with every item instead of the first 1. Further more, where you used unset($_SESSION["ActQueue"][$key][0]) does that only delete the "J.Paul" and not the other information on him like his forename or surname?

Comment: remove the `[0]` from `unset($_SESSION["ActQueue"][$key][0]);`

Comment: @Anant, thanks for your help again. I think I have managed to resolve the issue with `$_SESSION["ActQueue"] = array_values($_SESSION["ActQueue"]);` as it indexes the array so resets the keys making the rest of my code work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unset($_SESSION["ActQueue"][0]);
$_SESSION["ActQueue"] = array_values($_SESSION["ActQueue"]);
```

It seems that `unset()` does not always reset array keys. The function array_values redefines my array with the correct keys / indexes it.